# Set of ordinals less than a given ordinal

Tags: ordinals

Can anyone enlighten me about how this set can be well-ordered? That is, given any ordinal $\alpha$ the set of all ordinals less than $\alpha$, $W(\alpha)$, is well-ordered. I can show that this set is ordered by using "section" argument, but I can't see well-order property. Many thanks!

Comment: What is your definition of an _ordinal_?

Comment: The order type of a well-ordered set is called ordinal

Comment: Isnt't the set of ordinals less than $\alpha$ simply $\alpha$ itself?

Comment: @Hagen: If you consider the von Neumann definition of ordinals, then yes. If you consider them as equivalence classes of order types (a-la Cantor/Frege) then no.

Comment: Then how do you define the order between ordinals?   I assume it is something to the effect of $\alpha < \beta$ iff for each (some) well-ordered set $\langle X , \prec \rangle$ of order-type $\beta$ there is an $a \in X$ such that $\{ x \in X : x \prec a \}$ has order-type $\alpha$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh, right. But equivalence classes are so big and clumsy :(